# rails / streamio-ffmpeg - How to execute 2-pass encoding?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, video, encoding, ffmpeg

I'm using [streamio-ffmpeg](https://github.com/streamio/streamio-ffmpeg) to encode videos uploaded to my Rails application via ffmpeg. I want to encode the videos to .webm-format using the [VP9 coding format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VP9) and the [VP9 Encoding Guide](http://wiki.webmproject.org/ffmpeg/vp9-encoding-guide) of the WebM Project recommends using 2-pass encoding. I managed to get the videos encoding via streamio-ffmpeg using 1-pass encoding, but I can't figure out how to handle the 2-pass encoding.

Here my setup so far:

```
# create two tempfiles for the video and a still
video = Tempfile.new(["video", ".webm"], binmode: true)
still = Tempfile.new(["still", ".jpg"], binmode: true)

# new FFMPEG
movie = FFMPEG::Movie.new(original.path)

# extract still from video
movie.screenshot(still.path)

# encode video
options = %w(-c:v libvpx-vp9 -b:v 1000K -threads 8 -speed 4 -tile-columns 6 -frame-parallel 1 -auto-alt-ref 1 -lag-in-frames 25 -c:a libvorbis -b:a 64k -f webm)
movie.transcode(video.path, options)
```

The command to do a 2-pass encoding with ffmpeg would be:

```
ffmpeg -i <source> -c:v libvpx-vp9 -pass 1 ... -f webm /dev/null
ffmpeg -i <source> -c:v libvpx-vp9 -pass 2 ... -f output.webm
```

In particular, I don't get how to pass the file of the first encoding step to the second step with streamio-ffmpeg. How would I apply these two steps to the syntax of `movie.transcode(output, options)`?

Thanks!